# Gitlab CI: Building Ionic App results in "unable to create new native thread" error

Tags: android, docker, gradle, ionic-framework, gitlab-ci

I am trying to build an Ionic Cordova App through the a gitlab ci pipline.
I've set up a gitlab runner, which is working for other builds fluently, but when building the ionic app with it fails.

All aproaches like setting system ulimit were already tried out. But since they only affect the system wide thread limit they seem not to have any affect on the gitlab runner inside its docker container.

```
  stage: mobile-build
  image: beevelop/ionic:latest
  cache:
    paths:
      - platforms/
      - plugins/
  artifacts: 
    paths:
      - platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk
  script: 
    - npm install
    - ionic cordova platform add android@^9.0.0
    - ionic cordova build android --release
```

The pipeline always results the following error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /opt/android
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
:wrapper
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
unable to create new native thread
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?
... costed my like 8hrs up to now

Answer (score 0):

After a couple more hours of investigation I've found out that the problem was the Linux V-Server on which the runner was located.

This server (Strato V-Server) got an incredible low Numproc value, which determines the global max process count (serverside 105, compared to my local working machine which got 4194304). - just stupid

This means it doesnt matter how high you set the process limit or java/docker memory. The gradle deamon just cant launch more threads cause the V-Server forbids it.